# Is zlib Type0 header data should be included in adler checksum calculation?

Tags: zlib, checksum

When calculating the Adler-32 checksum of uncompressed data in zlib format, should it include Type 0 (uncompressed data) data as well?

Comment: Okay, you got me thoroughly confused. There is no "uncompressed data in zlib format". Are you sure you don't mean an "uncompressed **block** in the Deflate format", as in  3.2.4. Non-compressed blocks (BTYPE=00)" in [RFC1951](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt)? (Which kind of answers your question, because then it is not  – per definition! –  *zlib compressed*, and thus does not need the Adler-32 checksum, which is only mentioned in [RFC1950](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zlib format does not support "type 0".  The only type supported by the zlib format is type 8, deflate.  Since purely stored data does not have a means to detect when it ends, it cannot be used as a zlib data type.  The type used must be self-terminating.

The deflate format internally supports a stored mode, which precedes chunks of uncompressed data with counts.

If the zlib format ever supports compression types other than 8, then yes, the Adler-32 would be computed over the uncompressed result of those methods of compression.